# Design a debug interface for Arduino MKR WIFI 1010

Tags: arduino, pcb, debugging, swd

I'm a TA at university, and for the next years students in microcontroller, I will design a debug interface for the Arduino MKR WIFI 1010.

The 6 pads on the back is the debug interface as shown in the schematic

[image: The back of the MKR WIFI 1010]

[image: Schematic showing signals from debug interface to the SAM D21 MCU]

Any ideas on how to make a shield/connector? I can design/produce PCBs at the university.

Requirements:

- The board should still be able to connect to the breadboard.
- Interface to a 2x5 1.27mm SWD debugger
- Optional: Reusability
- Optional: A solution that doesn't need soldering.

Comment: Look into pogo pins and some kind of holder, like a wooden block. Or if you are connecting a breadboard, you might need to do some kind of carrier board. Otherwise soldering those on isn't too difficult, but you'll need to bring it out to some wires/header because those might be right in the middle of the "trough", or short to the pins on either side.

Answer (score 0):

The pads on the back of the arduino are designed to have a double row vertical surface mount terminal strip soldered to it.

From there you can make a 'dupont' cable assembly to connect it to the debugger. Alternatively a number of adaptor boards exist to connect to common debuggers. Or create a pcb that can plug into the terminal strip and provides a connector of your choice.

(Height may be an issue, but there are low profile terminal strip assemblies.)

I found this page which may be of help: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=c8uhmcjvsmn453is1v0k9t0ui7&topic=442133.0